# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer break my hibernate session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have an issue in my Spring project when, after create my hibernateSession and TransactionManager I initilize a bean that extends **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** 
I dont know why but in that moment my hibermnate session is ruin to be used for the rest of my  DAO´s. The error that is throwing is this one.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

Any suggestions?

I´m trying to extract from database some data to create a properties class and set to a class that I´ve create that extends **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**

This is the class

```
 public class PropertiesSourceImpl extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{

public ConfigurationSource configurationSource;

public Properties properties;

public void init() {
    for (ConfigurationProperty prop : configurationSource.getEnabledConfigurationPropertiesByType(ConfigurationProperty.PropertyType.MAIL)) {
        System.out.println(prop);
       // properties.setProperty(prop.getPropertyKey(), prop.getPropertyValue());
    }
}

public Properties getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

@Required
public void setConfigurationSource(final ConfigurationSource configurationSource) {
    this.configurationSource = configurationSource;
}
```

}

and here my bean definition

```
<bean id="propertiesSource" class="nl.greenvalley.digipolis.config.PropertiesSourceImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="configurationSource" ref="configurationSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It isn't breaking your session, but in a `Bean(Factory)PostProcessor` no transactional context is available. Transactions are applied after all beans are initialized. In this specific bean you need to do manual transaction management (wrap the call inside a `TransactionTemplate`).

Comment: My ConfigurationSource service has a Dao whose interface is marked as @Transactional and works for some beans that using the session before Spring finish the initialization. But like I said is tricky, because just to have a class that extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer the rest of the beans that was using the hibernate session even transactional without any issue now have it and cannot make the request.

Comment: I dont uderstand pretty good what you means with wrap with TransactionTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Instead of use hibernate I just create a new session and transaction before the hibernate session and transaction would be created.

```
      SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void init() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<ConfigurationProperty> dbProperties = session.createCriteria(ConfigurationProperty.class).list();
        for (ConfigurationProperty property : dbProperties) {
            properties.setProperty(property.getPropertyKey(), property.getPropertyValue());
        }
        setProperties(properties);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```